# Estimating conditional probability P(A,B)/P(B) by using separate models for P(A, B) and P(B) vs marginalisation of P(A,B)?

Tags: bayesian, modeling, conditional-probability, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

edit: Tried to clarify the question.

Say I want to estimate $\frac{P(B | A) P(A)}{P(B)}$, and for some reason I can't estimate $P(A|B) = \frac{P(B | A) P(A)}{P(B)}$ directly. For the numerator, I can estimate the distributions $P(B|A)$ and $P(A)$ from the data for example by building a joint Bayesian model for $P(B | A)$ and $P(A)$ so that I get posterior draws from these distributions (i.e. the joint $P(A, B)$),

Now for $P(B)$ I can think two approaches, one would be to just estimate the marginal $P(B)$ directly ignoring the $A$ variable, or I could estimate $P(B)$ by marginalisation of $P(B | A) P(A) = P(A, B)$. Mathematically both approaches are identical, but can we say anything about which approach would be better in practice? What I am thinking here is that if I create a model for $B | A$ and $B$ separately, there is no guarantee that these model are compatible in a way that integrating $A$ out of $P(A, B)$ does not necessarily lead to same $P(B)$ I get from estimating $P(B)$ directly. Can we say anything about potential bias or other problems of the approach where I build two separate models instead of just $P(A,B)$? In my case I sometimes get these kind of formulas by using Pearl's do-calculus, although I'm interested in this in more general terms, like is there some consistency issues with essentially modelling the same variable twice (by $P(B|A)$ and $P(B)$) vs. modelling only the joint $P(A, B)$.

Comment: Could you tell us more what exactly is your data and the models you are using? If you can estimate $P(B|A)$ from the data, why can't you have a model for $P(A|B)$?

Comment: Good question, thanks. When trying to frame this in general terms I actually made an error, the left-hand side should not be taken as P(A|B) but just some functional which can be written as the right-hand side. For example, we are interested in some interventional distribution P(A | do(B)) (by using Pearl's notation), and we happen to get an identifying formula which looks like P(A,B)/P(B). I'll try to edit the question.

Comment: Those might be important details to add to the body of the question.

Comment: Maybe yeah, although I'm interested in this in more general terms, like is there some consistency issues with essentially modelling the same variable twice (by P(B|A) and P(B)).